# Non-starting Uno

Tags: starting

Good morning to all

I have a Uno 1.1 Mia 2001 model. I have a problem of it not starting. One morning my wife was driving with it and some 1km from home, the car just died and did not want to start. I did check the petrol pump and it was pumping ok. So I checked for spark, no spark. I thought it could be the ignition module because I know it gives problems, I replaced it. Still nothing. So I changed the coil, still no spark. So now I don't know. I am all out of ides. It does crank but just don't want to start but when I turn the ignition key from on to the  off position it sparks but only once.

Answer (score 1):

**td dr** - I'm thinking your timing belt might be the issue.

I'm not too familiar with the Uno Mia's 1.1l engine, but would assume from the size it is a 3-cylinder engine. It should be an overhead cam design, with the distributor hung off the side of the valve cover. If all of this is true, pop the oil filler cap and have a look to see if you can see the cam shaft or at least some of the working internals of the head. If so, have someone crank the engine while you are looking. If the internals do not move, the timing belt is most likely toast. With the distributor stuck on the end of the cam shaft, if the cam shaft isn't spinning, you won't get any spark from the spark plugs.

**EDIT:**

If the timing belt is in good stead, it could be the ignition control module (ICM) which picks up the timing signals and sets the ball in motion for the spark to occur. This would be harder to determine. Some ICMs can be checked at the parts store.

Comment: the distributor is hanning of the side and cam belt is also fine and when i turn the engin turn the engin all timming marks are on place it is a four cylinder but i see that there is no spark from the coil wire to the distributor cap

Comment: How did you determine the timing marks are in place? Which timing marks did you look at?

Comment: @J-pEcroignard - Check the edit.

Comment: morning on the instection hole on the gearbox because the flywheel is holding the timing mark for the crank and the timing blelt pully on the cam is holding the other timing mark

Comment: and i did also replace the ignition control module

Answer (score -1):

The problem with one spark is the ignition key. It's when you turn the key to start it swings but will only spark once when you take your hand off the cranking. My car did that after someone tried to steal it, the busted ignition still doesn't work but I got it to drive just now I have to move the key a bit back if I want the wipers to work as well

Answer (score -2):

Is battery fully charged and working? 'One spark only' sounds like a discharged battery.

Comment: yes battery is full and finewhat bothers me is that when i turn the ignition of there is a spark but when i turn it on no spark

Comment: It wouldn't crank with a dead battery anyway